# Building a levels with tasks app in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I am new to django and I am building a simple app that has some levels with tasks which a user have to complete. It has 7 levels, a user have to complete a specific level (which has a task) to unlock the next level. Unless he completes the previous task he can't access the next level or the webpage or url. So there is a Groups thing in django. Shall I use that to achieve the functionality or is there any other stuff I shall do/use?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, What is this "Groups" thing in Django, is there a link? Why do you think this would work for you?  Are there other things you have tried? If not why not?

Comment: @Artisan I want to achieve the functionality of levels like feature just like a game. If you have something is store plz suggest. Thank you.